# How to inspect dynamic content in browser debugging extensions?

Tags: html, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I have popup window, appearing on my site when mouse is hover on some object. Once this happens I can press (in Chrome) Ctrl-Shift-C and activate element selection mode and select any element inside popup window. But once I made selection, web page goes to normal flow and popup window immediately disappears since mouse is not in correct position anymore.

Is it possible to overcome this situation somehow? For example, select element, but not terminate selection mode?

Comment: I usually set a breakpoint on mouse events in devtools -> sources -> event listener breakpoints -> mouse. It pauses the js engine so the element stays until I resume execution.

Answer (score 1):

Both Chrome and Firefox have the ability, in their respective DevTools, to set, and keep set, pseudo-classes like hover, active and focus. This allows you to work with the page as if the mouse was interacting with the element(s) for which you change a pseudo-class.

The following show toggling the hover pseudo-class on the Documentation link in the SO top-nav bar.

Here is what it looks like in Chrome:

[image: Toggle pseudo-class in Chrome]

Here is what it looks like in Firefox:

[image: Toggle pseudo-class in Firefox]